# Win32 Window with OpenGL context draw nothing

Tags: winapi, opengl

I wrote a small Win32 window with a OpenGL (On my pc with 4.4) context.
Than I generated a file with OpenGL 3.3 function pointers with the [OpenGL Loader Generator](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home).
Now all seems to work, but nothing will be drawn.
The only thing that works is, that I can clear the screen with a given color.
But I don't get a triangle drawn.
After that I tried to use the windows gl.h function pointers(OpenGL v.1.1) and tried to draw a simple triangle without VBO's and shaders.
But there will still nothing be drawn.
Whats wrong?

```
#include "glw.h"


#include <windows.h>
#include "wgl.h"
#include "gl.h"
#include "log.h"


HINSTANCE instanceHandle;
WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
HWND windowHandle;
HDC deviceContextHandle;
HGLRC openglContextHandle;

bool isCloseRequested;


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowMessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            isCloseRequested = true;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
}


void glw::Create()
{
    if(!(instanceHandle = GetModuleHandle(0)))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to get instance handle!");
    }

    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowMessageHandler;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = instanceHandle;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "atomus_window_class";
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = "menu_name";
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to register window class!");
    }

    if(!(windowHandle = CreateWindowEx( 0,
                                    "atomus_window_class",
                                    "atomus title",
                                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    800,
                                    600,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    instanceHandle,
                                    0)))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to create window!");
    }

    if(!(deviceContextHandle = GetDC(windowHandle)))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to get device context handle!");
    }

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelFormatDescriptor;
    pixelFormatDescriptor.nSize = sizeof(pixelFormatDescriptor);
    pixelFormatDescriptor.nVersion = 1;
    pixelFormatDescriptor.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pixelFormatDescriptor.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pixelFormatDescriptor.cColorBits = 32;
    pixelFormatDescriptor.cDepthBits = 32;
    pixelFormatDescriptor.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    unsigned int pixelFormat;

    if(!(pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(deviceContextHandle, &pixelFormatDescriptor)))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to find suitable pixel format!");
    }
    if(!SetPixelFormat(deviceContextHandle, pixelFormat, &pixelFormatDescriptor))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to set pixel format!");
    }

    HGLRC temporaryContext = wglCreateContext(deviceContextHandle);

    if(!temporaryContext)
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to create temporary context!");
    }
    if (!(wglMakeCurrent(deviceContextHandle, temporaryContext)))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to activate temporary context!");
    }

    int major;
    int minor;
    gl::GetIntegerv(gl::MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
    gl::GetIntegerv(gl::MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
    if(!(major >= 3 && minor >= 3))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create opengl 3.3 ist not supported!");
    }

    int attribs[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, major,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, minor,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0
    };

    PFNWGLCREATEBUFFERREGIONARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATEBUFFERREGIONARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress( "wglCreateContextAttribsARB" );

    if(!wglCreateContextAttribsARB)
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to find pointer to wglCreateContextAttribsARB function!");
    }
    if(!(openglContextHandle = (HGLRC)wglCreateContextAttribsARB(deviceContextHandle, 0, (UINT)attribs)))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to create forward compatible context!");
    }

    wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );
    wglDeleteContext( temporaryContext );

    if(!wglMakeCurrent(deviceContextHandle, (HGLRC)openglContextHandle))
    {
        log::logRuntimeError("glw::create failed to activate forward compatible context!");
    }

    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(windowHandle);

    isCloseRequested = false;
}
void glw::Destroy()
{
    DestroyWindow(windowHandle);
    windowHandle = 0;

    UnregisterClass(windowClass.lpszClassName, instanceHandle);
}
void glw::Update()
{
    MSG message;
    while (PeekMessage (&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) //Or use an if statement
    {
         TranslateMessage (&message);
         DispatchMessage (&message);
    }
}
void glw::SwapBuffers()
{
    ::SwapBuffers(deviceContextHandle);
}
bool glw::IsCloseRequested()
{
    return isCloseRequested;
}
```

Comment: You're creating a Core Profile context. Is your rendering code written for the Core Profile? This means for example that it needs to use VAO (Vertex Array Object) for the vertex data, it needs to provide shaders written in GLSL, and it can't use any deprecated features.

Comment: I know, I tried it with vbo, shaders usw.

Comment: you haven't included any of the drawing code, only the window creation and management code.  When and where do you actually execute the rendering?  Where you you execute the buffer swap?